# Flex: How to Reference What's Been Clicked When Using an ItemRenderer?

Tags: apache-flex, itemrenderer

I've got a Tilelist and I'm using an ItemRenderer, which is a Button.

I don't understand how to reference what was clicked. So, if the first tile (which is the first Obect) is clicked, how do I know that that particular one was clicked.

```
<mx:ArrayCollection id="myAC">
    <mx:Array>
    <mx:Object id="first" label="1" />
    <mx:Object label="2" />
    <mx:Object label="3" />
    <mx:Object label="4" />
    </mx:Array>
</mx:ArrayCollection>



ItemRenderer:

<mx:Button xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
click="Alert.show( 'This was Clicked')">


<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
import mx.controls.Alert;
]]>
</mx:Script>

</mx:Button>
```

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MouseEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2).[target](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#target) will give you the item was was clicked

If you want to access the element in your dataPRovider, you can use the data property in your itemRenderer.  Something like this:

```
<mx:Button xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
click="Alert.show( data['label'] + ' was Clicked')"
```

Comment: www.Flextras.com, You've helped me out a few times. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help!  Feel free to give me some "up-vote" love at your own discretion.